# Move search box to the center in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I'm using a bootstrap nav bar as is from [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=responsive-navbar-inverted-variation) reference and I'm trying that on mobile devices user do not need to click on the menu icon to search on the page. So trying to display search-box just after the Brand in responsive mode.

Bootstrap looks like this in normal desktop browser:

[image: Desktop Broswer Nav bar]

And looks like this in responsive mode:

[image: Responsive nav bar]

I have to move that search box and login option to show in the center after Brand on mobile devices. I tried playing with css to move search box out of nav bar, but its screwing my entire HTML.

Can someone guide me, how to do that?
Here is the

```
[JSFiddle Link][4] - https://jsfiddle.net/mzy1sak3/1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we click nav-bar toggle button in mobile device then nav-bar collapse menu will show up,in that nav menu has default nav-bar search option.It can not be changed without changing bootstrap default behavior but there is a tricky option. You can hide it by adding extra class named as "hidden-xs".Then you can put another div,with "visible-xs" class where you can put that form for mobile device.

Here is the sample html:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>

                <div class="visible-xs">
                    <form class="navbar-search-sm" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <ul class="list-inline navbar-links-sm">
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left hidden-xs" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navbar -->
```

And you can customize css like this:

```
.navbar-search-sm{ display: inline-block; margin-top: 8px; }
.navbar-search-sm .form-group{ width: 300px; margin-bottom: 0; }
.navbar-links-sm{ display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px; }
```

Comment: @GiulioBambini- Thanks. This is somewhat I want. need some more help. This design is perfect when seen on iPad mode but on mobile devices search box is coming down  after menubar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach
Using iPhone 5 and 5S screen resolution

wrap the ul input tag and the login div in another div with id `form_login` and below the above style

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  #form_login {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
  }
  #navbarCollapse {
    padding-top: 120px;
  }
}
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/pr7y6bd8/2/) (resize window width)

You will need to apply other media rules for other devices

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I'm trying is, on mobile devices user do not need to click on the menu icon to search on the page. So that trying to display search-box just after the Brand in responsive mode. Will update my question.